# Why do i get NA using the interval function in lubridate?

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate

I have a data frame with dates ordered as shown below. I try to get a column with intervals from the POSIXct DateTime column using the interval function in lubridate. That is:

```
Interval_DateTime = interval(DateTime, lead(DateTime))
```

I do not understand why I get `NA` in every third row, does anyone know why?

```
DateTime

2020-09-17 06:00:00      

2020-09-17 14:00:00      

2020-09-17 22:00:00       

2020-09-18 06:00:00       

2020-09-18 14:00:00      

2020-09-18 22:00:00       

...


Interval_DateTime

2020-09-17 06:00:00 UTC--2020-09-17 14:00:00 UTC

2020-09-17 14:00:00 UTC--2020-09-17 22:00:00 UTC

NA

2020-09-18 06:00:00 UTC--2020-09-18 14:00:00 UTC

2020-09-18 14:00:00 UTC--2020-09-18 22:00:00 UTC

NA

...
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be because your data is grouped. Try ungrouping the data first.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Interval_DateTime = interval(DateTime, lead(DateTime))) -> df

df
```